# How can I improve the file upload speed for big size?

Tags: android, ios, http, file-upload, upload

I am developing file upload application on Android OS.

Basically I am using HttpURLConnection and it is required.

About same file size, IOS is very fast and I used AFNetworking.

But Android is too slow, please advice what I am missing.

Here is the source code what I used.

Thank you.

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            conn.setReadTimeout(3600*1000);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

            File temp = new File(file_path);
            int length = (int)temp.length();
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);

            conn.setUseCaches (false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "xxx");

            conn.connect();

            OutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_path);

            int bytesAvailable = in.available();

            int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 300;
            int totalSize = bytesAvailable;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            long bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {    
                out.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                bytesAvailable = in.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }    

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            rd.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;

        } finally {

            if(conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried by dividing your file into number of chunks and then upload

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but your answer is not useful, if possible then would you please provide me the sample code? Also Already I have tried chunk mode. but no lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [HttpClient jar](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) download the latest HttpClient jar, add it to your project, and upload the file using the following method:

```
private void uploadFile(String filePath) throws ParseException, IOException {

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR_URL);

FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(filePath));
StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename: " + filePath);
StringBody description = new StringBody("This is a video of the agent");
StringBody code = new StringBody(realtorCodeStr);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("filePath", filebodyVideo);
reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
reqEntity.addPart("code", code);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

// DEBUG
System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity( );

// DEBUG
System.out.println( response.getStatusLine( ) );
if (resEntity != null) {
System.out.println( EntityUtils.toString( resEntity ) );
} // end if

if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent( );
} // end if

httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Also can I use upload progress status with HttpClient,jar?

Comment: I used cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient, but still I have issue.

Comment: May i know how much is the expected file size you used to transfer ? If its larger than 250 Mb , i will suggest you to use a file accelerator like file catalyst  or amazon s3 etc..  For noraml senario you may use Retrofit / Loopj library for easy handling of file uploads

Comment: exactly it's 25M